# How to identify what exact model of STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I have a consumer device that I know uses a STM32 microcontroller that I'd like to hack a bit.  Is there a reliable way to communicate with the chip and determine its exact model, so I can locate the correct datasheet?  Nothing is printed on the chip itself.

Comment: Use a debugger to connect via SWD.

Comment: That's what my research has shown, but surely not all STM32s have the same pins, right?

Comment: Package and at least a guess of the STM32 family would narrow the search.

Comment: I got a ST-LINK V2, and the ST-LINk Utility seems like the correct program.  However I'm having trouble getting it to recognize that I've connected it to the SWDIO/SWCLK/VAPP/GND pins.  Still trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: STLInk has its own supply for the uC. Try connecting it to the STLInk's Debugging port without any other external power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up buying an ST-Linkv2 and connecting to the SWD interface with some [tiny clips](https://www.reichelt.de/de/de/challenger-clip-gelb-clip-6800-ge-p63459.html).  However the programmer refuses to detect the presence of the device.  It seems likely that readout protection (RDP) is enabled, preventing access to the flash memory.  Short of some sort of [vulnerability](https://hackaday.com/2020/03/24/breaking-into-a-secure-facility-stm32-flash/), there's no way to determine the exact model, let alone re-program it.

Comment: I would think the model of device would still be detectable. Read out protection doesn't prevent you from reprogramming a chip, only retrieving the flash contents.

Comment: @Drew: Level 1 allows wiping the chip but not reading it.  Level 2 disables JTAG and SWD entirely.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

try figuring out which pin is GND (this should be easy), which +3.3 V (can try using multimeter and continuity mode), SWDIO and SWCLK. Connect them to ST-link V2 and use "STM32 ST-LINK Utility" software and connect to target, it automatically detects device ID (chip name). It also reads out memory, so this might be useful for further moding.

Comment: How would you identify SWDIO and SWCLK if you don't know how to identify them?

Comment: connecting them backwards, in theory, shouldn't harm the device nor the programmer, one is just pulsed signal, the other actual data, if connecting one way doesn't respond, switching them should work. Distinguishing GND is easy, 3.3V might be tricky, but following track to other components could be useful and power lines are usually thicker than signal ones.

Comment: Most devices have some kind of programming header, and gnd and VDD can be deduced.